# why are my delete cell variables not deleting the last inserted row?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to delete the last inserted row in the add row function in my code. can someone explain to my why is the delete function code not working? here's code. I'm a complete newbie to coding, so please don't bash me. I have a theory that I should get the table row element and insert a delete row function with a
negative one as its parameter.

```js
function addRow() {
  var getTable = document.getElementById("tbody")
  var tableSize = getTable.rows.length;
  var row = getTable.insertRow(tableSize)
  var getName = document.getElementById("fname")
  var getLastName = document.getElementById("lname")
  var getPassword = document.getElementById("password")

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = tableSize + 1;
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = getName.value;
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = getLastName.value;
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = getPassword.value;
}


function deleteRow() {
  var getTable = document.getElementById("tbody")
  var tableSize = getTable.rows.length;
  var row = getTable.insertRow(tableSize)
  var getName = document.getElementById("fname")
  var getLastName = document.getElementById("lname")
  var getPassword = document.getElementById("password")

  var cell1 = row.deleteCell(0).innerHTML = tableSize + 1;
  var cell1 = row.deleteCell(1).innerHTML = getName.value;
  var cell2 = row.deleteCell(2).innerHTML = getLastName.value;
  var cell3 = row.deleteCell(3).innerHTML = getPassword.value;




}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="fname" /> <br /> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="lname" /> <br /> Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="password" /> <br />
<button onclick="addRow()">Add</button><br /><br />


<button onClick="deleteRow()">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing an "**var row = getTable.insertRow(tableSize)**" in your **deleteRow** function

use

```
var row = getTable.deleteRow(tableSize - 1)
```

**Note** : you have to use

> tableSize - 1

since index is 0 based, also you don't need any lines following the above line

here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tLo810kv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can write your delete function as below

```js
function addRow() {
  var getTable = document.getElementById("tbody")
  var tableSize = getTable.rows.length;
  var row = getTable.insertRow(tableSize)
  var getName = document.getElementById("fname")
  var getLastName = document.getElementById("lname")
  var getPassword = document.getElementById("password")

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = tableSize + 1;
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = getName.value;
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = getLastName.value;
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = getPassword.value;
}


function deleteFunction() {
var table1 = document.getElementById("table");
var rowCount = table1.rows.length;

table1.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="fname" /> <br /> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="lname" /> <br /> Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="password" /> <br />
<button onclick="addRow()">Add</button><br /><br />


<button onClick="deleteFunction()">Delete</button>
```